# Save custom device width and height in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome developer tools in chrome can simulate some device dimensions and even we can set custom width(x) and height(y) for viewport. my question is can we save this custom width or height with custom name or just save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Yes, you can save custom presets. Just click the `More overrides` button in the top right (represented as three horizontal dots). The emulation drawer should show up in the Dev-tools. You can click `Save As`  button and assign a name to the custom preset. The new preset should then show up in the list of Models.</s>

Check out the [official DevTools documentation on this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#save-custom-presets) for more detailed steps.

Edit: This seems to have changed in the newer versions of Chrome. [matharden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807877/976897) includes the correct steps: inside the devtools, go to `Settings`, select `Devices` in the left navigation and select `Add custom device...`

Comment: Things have changed and the Save As button no longer appears in the emulation drawer. Check out joefurniss's answer instead.

Comment: This has now move, [see below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599155/save-custom-device-width-and-height-in-chrome-developer-tools/#33807877).

Comment: Downvoted, reason for it is this answer is no longer correct. Correct answer is @matharden's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions this is found in...

1. Developer Tools (CTRL+SHIFT/OPTION+CMD+I)
2. Settings (F1)
3. Devices
4. Add custom device…

As specified in the [Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#custom-devices) Chrome docs.

Chrome Canary now has this conveniently found under "Edit…" in the 'Responsive' drop-down menu when in 'device mode' (CTRL+SHIFT/OPTION+CMD+M when developer tools are open).

Comment: this works, but does not seem to save the custom device after closing chrome.  Is there a way to save the custom device, and make it a default so when the browser opens it defaults to the custom device?

Comment: A few years after the answer was given but: Is there any way to edit an already added custom device? I only seem to be able to enable/disable them. Not edit them.

Answer (score 2):

If you bring up the developer tools, click the settings cog in the corner and then select Devices from the left-hand menu, there is an option at the bottom of that page to add a custom device.

Comment: I liked the old way better (Save As option in the emulation drawer) but this answer now appears to be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I've added this answer, saving screen resolutions seems to have been disabled.

I created a preset (1024x768) whilst it was still possible, and I can still access that preset, but there's no longer a Save option where it did exist (as @Chirag64 described).

There's no mention of 'save' in the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode, either :(

I  had a quick look around in chrome://flags and my ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome directory, but couldn't find reference to the preference I have saved...

Comment: it's in the Developer Tools settings, [see my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599155/save-custom-device-width-and-height-in-chrome-developer-tools/#33807877).